Render an image from a pixel buffer in egui
I am trying to add an image to my window from a pixel buffer in memory. (right now I am using cpu memory because I'm on a macbook anyway).
I don't want the image to be cached because this will be the single frame of a video (but I'm trying to make it work with a single image first, for the same reason I'll start with an hardcoded pixel buffer to begin with).
I will cut the eframe/egui bolierplate ang go to the main part inside the update fn:
egui_extras::install_image_loaders(ctx);

...
ui.heading("Video player");
let pixels = vec![0; 10_000]; // 100x100 8-bit rgb image (all black)
let img = egui::Image::from_bytes("bytes://foo", pixels);
ui.add(img);

I have added egui_extras of course. Now when I run the app I can see the window with the heading but instead of the black rectangle this warning is shown:

Some of my questions regarding the API remain unanswered also due to the lack of documentation and examples:

I am creating an image from a pixel buffer but am not specifying size of the image nor pixel format, which one is the default?
What is the uri parameter of egui::Image::from_bytes() for? I have filled it with a dummy String but its purpose is obscure to me. (There is no description in the docs)
What is causing the error? I have added the required crate and called the setup method install_image_loaders(ctx)


Image::from_bytes expects encoded image data, not just raw pixel data (even if it's an uncompressed format like BMP, it still needs the headers in the data). It uses the file extension from the URI to select the appropriate decoder. Creating an image from raw pixel data probably requires going through a Texture, but I don't know how to do it.

You can use a ColorImage and then supply this to a Texture. An example can be found in this noise-functions-demo source, which has this form (edited down to the essence):
    let pixels: Vec<egui::Color32> = ...;
    // loop to fill out pixels {
    // let color: egui::Color32 = ...;
    // pixels[i] = color;

    texture.set(
            egui::ColorImage {
                size: ...,
                pixels: pixels,
            },
            egui::TextureOptions::NEAREST,
    );

    let size = texture.size_vec2();
    let sized_texture = egui::load::SizedTexture::new(texture, size);
    ui.add(egui::Image::new(sized_texture).fit_to_exact_size(size));


What about the URI?

Sounds like you need a valid image extension like .png added to your bytes:// URL, e.g. :  bytes://foo.png, see https://docs.rs/egui/latest/egui/widgets/enum.ImageSource.html#variant.Bytes

But, the Image::from_bytes method seems to expect raw byte data for an actual image storage format. E.g. the bytes of a PNG of JPEG image. Not raw pixel data. Though I could be wrong, the documentation and examples are lacking here.
